# String conditional tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, conditionals, xstring

I am trying to make a print command for a board game (Amazons). I specify the dimensions and board state, so \AmazonsBoard{3}{3}{WXX---BXX} will draw a small 3x3 board. There are 4 different square types, "W, B, -, X" and I want to draw something seperate for each of them. The (stripped down) code I have is,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\newcommand{\AmazonsBoard}[3]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\newcounter{index}
\foreach \x in {1,...,#1}
\foreach \y in {1,...,#2}
{
    \setcounter{index}{(\x)+(#2 - \y) * #1};
    \draw[draw = black] (\x, \y) rectangle ++(1, 1);
    \IfStrEq{W}{\StrChar{#3}{\value{index}}} 
    {
        \draw[color= black](\x + 0.5,\y + 0.5) node{\StrChar{#3}{\value{index}}};
    }{}
}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}

\AmazonsBoard{3}{3}{WXX---BXX}

\end{document}
```

But this does not work because of `\IfStrEq{W}{\StrChar{#3}{\value{index}}}`. It does not do what I think it should do, namely somethhing like `if (#3[index] == "W"){}`. Why is this not the case and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `pgfmath` expressions in `\setcounter`, but that's not the only problem.

Also `\StrChar{#3}{\value{index}` can't be used in `\IfStrEq` for two reasons: it is not expandable and `\value{index}` is not a string, but an abstract number.

This works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\AmazonsBoard}[3]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x in {1,...,#1}{
      \foreach \y in {1,...,#2}{
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\tempA}{int((\x)+(#2 - \y) * #1)}
        \draw[draw = black] (\x, \y) rectangle ++(1, 1);
        \StrChar{#3}{\tempA}[\tempB]
        \IfStrEq{W}{\tempB}{%
          \draw[color= black](\x + 0.5,\y + 0.5) node{\tempB};%
        }{}%
      }
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\AmazonsBoard{3}{3}{WXX-W-BXX}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Instead of having a bunch of conditionals that check your one letter `W`, `X`, `B` or `-` you could just define some styles that have that letter in their name, say

```
amazonsBoard/W/.style={fill=red},
amazonsBoard/X/.style={fill=blue!50},
amazonsBoard/B/.style={fill=green},
amazonsBoard/-/.style={fill=gray},
```

All you now have to do with your path is

```
\path[amazonsBoard/\macroThatHasThatLetterStored] …;
% or to be on the safe side
\path[amazonsBoard/\macroThatHasThatLetterStored/.try] …;
```

(The [handler `.try`](https://tikz.dev/pgfkeys#handlers/.try) means that PGFKeys will try that key but doesn't complain when it isn't found.)

If you'd now accept the input in the form of

```
{{W,X,X},{-,-,-},{B,X,X}}
```

i.e. a list of rows where each row is its own list,
your macro can be defined as

```
\newcommand{\AmazonsBoard}[2][]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[#1]
\foreach[count=\rowY] \row in {#2} {
  \foreach[count=\colX] \column in \row {
    \draw[black, amazonsBoard/\column/.try]
      (\colX,\rowY) rectangle node{\column} ++(1, 1);
  }
}
\end{tikzpicture}}
```

and with

```
\AmazonsBoard[
  amazonsBoard/W/.style={fill=red},
  amazonsBoard/X/.style={fill=blue!50},
  amazonsBoard/B/.style={fill=green},
  amazonsBoard/-/.style={fill=gray},
]{{W,X,X},{-,-,-},{B,X,X}}
```

you already get

[image]

without having to manipulate strings.

---

But you wanted to leave out the `,` right?

Here, I define a `no separator` key which customizes `\foreach`s list parser so that it only grabs one token (i.e. one letter) and uses that as its element. (The `...` syntax won't work anymore, of course.)

Now you only need to give the number of columns and with a few [`evaluate`ions](https://tikz.dev/pgffor#pgf/foreach/evaluate)
your `\AmazonsBoard` command can figure the rest out on its own.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{
  /pgf/foreach/no separator/.code={% token for token
    \def\pgffor@scan@custom##1{\def\pgffor@value{##1}\pgffor@scanned}%
    \def\pgffor@scan@custom@comma,{\pgfutil@ifnextchar\pgffor@stop
        \pgffor@scanone{\pgffor@scan@custom,}}%
    \def\pgffor@scan{\pgfutil@ifnextchar,\pgffor@scan@custom@comma{%
      \pgfutil@ifnextchar\pgffor@stop
      \pgffor@scanone\pgffor@scan@custom}}}}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\AmazonsBoard}[3][]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[#1]
\foreach[
  count=\i from 0, no separator, % ← !
  evaluate=\i as \colX using {mod(\i,#2)},
  evaluate=\i as \rowY using {int(\i/#2)}
] \elem in {#3} {
    \draw[black, amazonsBoard/\elem/.try]
      (\colX,\rowY) rectangle node{\elem} ++(1, 1);}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\AmazonsBoard[
  amazonsBoard/W/.style={fill=red},
  amazonsBoard/X/.style={fill=blue!50},
  amazonsBoard/B/.style={fill=green},
  amazonsBoard/-/.style={fill=gray},
]{3}{WXX---BXX}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you still want to use `xstring` you need to extract `\elem` first: `\StrChar{<string>}{<index>}[\elem]`.